How does Gen 1 StarTram manage to overcome atmospheric drag at the 4-8 km altitude?
I'm reading about StarTram, and if I understand correctly, the idea of the Generation 1 design is to have a vacuum tube under a mountain slope, exiting into the atmosphere at the altitude of 4 to 8 km. However, I don't fully understand the idea:

Do I understand it correctly that the acceleration given in the tube in the Gen 1 design is supposed to be enough for getting out of the atmosphere at the orbital velocity?
If that's the case, how is StarTram supposed to deal with the atmospheric drag? The air density is still relatively high at 4-8 km.
If it is possible to launch payload at higher-than-orbital velocity at 4-8 km, then what is the point of the Lofstrom Loop? I thought the whole point of constructing a megastructure at the altitude of 80 km is that the atmospheric drag at lower altitudes is too high for payloads at the orbital velocity.

EDIT: According to @ErinAnne, the answer to question 1 is "yes", and the answer to question 2 is in the paper:

Launch at (8+ΔV) km/sec, with sufficient ΔV so that the cargo craft velocity is 8 km/sec after it passes through the atmosphere.


That is, the paper says that adding up to about 1 km/s to the muzzle velocity is enough for dealing with the atmospheric drag.
I have one more question, then:

Who is right? The proponents of StarTram, who claim that payloads can be launched from an altitude of 4-8 km at a speed of about 9 km/s, or the proponents of the Lofstrom Loop, who seem to assume that launch at such speeds requires the much less dense atmosphere at an altitude of many tens of kilometres? It seems that only one side can be right.


relevant language seems to start on page 6 of the linked StarTram paper, last paragraph. The answer to your first two questions--at least as claimed by the authors--are in there. The answer to the third question seems like it's "disagreement over which megastructure to build".

@ErinAnne Thanks for confirming my suspicions about the answers to questions 1 and 2. In light of this, I have added an additional question.

FWIW, Keith Lofstrom posted an answer about his loop several years ago https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/409766/123208

Could the downvoters please explain how I can improve my questions?

Nobody's answering, so I'll share what I've found.
Max q (maximum dynamic pressure)
The key concept here seems to be max q (maximum dynamic pressure):

Dynamic pressure q is defined in incompressible fluid dynamics as
$q={\tfrac {1}{2}}\rho v^{2}$
where ρ is the local air density, and v is the vehicle's velocity.


For a launch of a space vehicle from the ground, dynamic pressure is:

zero at lift-off, when the air density ρ is high but the vehicle's speed v = 0;
zero outside the atmosphere, where the speed v is high, but the air density ρ = 0;
always non-negative, given the quantities involved.

During the launch, the vehicle speed increases but the air density decreases as the vehicle rises. Therefore, by Rolle's theorem, there is a point where the dynamic pressure is maximal.


During a typical Apollo mission, the max q (also just over 0.3 atmospheres) occurred between 13 and 14 kilometres (43,000–46,000 ft) of altitude; approximately the same values occur for the SpaceX Falcon 9.
The point of max q is a key milestone during a space vehicle launch, as it is the point at which the airframe undergoes maximum mechanical stress.

Dynamic pressure at different altitudes
In order to investigate max q at different altitudes, I wrote the following code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (9, 9)

altitude_to_air_density_dict = {
    # Data from http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm
    # altitude (m): density (kg/m^3)
    0:      1.22500,
    1000:   1.11164,
    2000:   1.00649,
    3000:   9.09122E-1,
    4000:   8.19129E-1,
    5000:   7.36116E-1,
    6000:   6.59697E-1,
    7000:   5.89501E-1,
    8000:   5.25168E-1,
    9000:   4.66348E-1,
    10000:  4.12707E-1,
    12000:  3.10828E-1,
    15000:  1.93674E-1,
    20000:  8.80349E-2,
    25000:  3.94658E-2,
    30000:  1.80119E-2,
    35000:  8.21392E-3,
    40000:  3.85101E-3,
    45000:  1.88129E-3,
    50000:  9.77525E-4,
    60000:  2.88321E-4,
    70000:  7.42430E-5,
    80000:  1.57005E-5,
}

altitude_to_density = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        altitude_to_air_density_dict,
        orient='index',
        columns=['air_density']
    )
    .rename_axis('altitude')
    .reset_index()
)

def air_density(h):
    """Calculate the air density at altitude h (m)."""
    return np.interp([h],
                     altitude_to_density.altitude,
                     altitude_to_density.air_density)[0]

def dynamic_pressure(v, h):
    """Calculate dynamic pressure given velocity v (m/s) and altitude h (m)."""
    rho = air_density(h)
    return 0.5 * rho * v**2

def convert_units(df):
    return df.assign(
        altitude=lambda df: df.altitude / 1000,  # m to km
        velocity=lambda df: df.velocity / 1000,  # m/s to km/s
        dynamic_pressure=lambda df: df.dynamic_pressure / 100000,  # Pascals to atmospheres
    )

Now we can plot dynamic pressure at different altitudes, assuming the vehicle is moving at the orbital speed + delta v of about 1 km/s.
df_orig_units = pd.DataFrame().assign(
    altitude=np.linspace(0, 80000, 801),  # altitude from 0 to 80 km
    velocity=np.full(801, 9000),  # speed is always 9 km/s (orbital velocity + delta v mentioned above)
    dynamic_pressure=lambda df: dynamic_pressure(df.velocity, df.altitude)
)
df = convert_units(df_orig_units)
ax = df.plot(
    x='altitude',
    y='dynamic_pressure',
    legend=False,
    grid=True,
    xlabel="altitude (km)",
    ylabel="dynamic pressure (atm)",
)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 80, 17))
ax.set_yticks([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
plt.show()


As we can see, the dynamic pressure at low altitudes is huge, measured in hundreds of atmospheres. We can more easily check at what altitudes it becomes reasonable if we use the logarithmic scale:
ax = df.plot(
    x='altitude',
    y='dynamic_pressure',
    legend=False,
    grid=True,
    xlabel="altitude (km)",
    ylabel="dynamic pressure (atm)",
    logy=True,
)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 80, 17))
ax.set_yticks([5e-3, 1e-2, 5e-2, 1e-1, 5e-1, 1, 5, 10, 50, 1e2, 5e2])
plt.show()


We can see that dynamic pressure gets down to 1 atm between 40 and 45 km of altitude, and gets to typical values experienced by rockets (0.3, see above) between 50 and 55 km.
Verification
In order to verify my code, I downloaded altitude and velocity data from a Falcon 9 launch and calculated dynamic pressure:
# Jason-3 data
# from https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=40983.0
jason3 = pd.read_csv("jason3.csv").dropna()
jason3.columns = ["time", "altitude", "velocity"]
df_orig_units = jason3.assign(
    dynamic_pressure=lambda df: dynamic_pressure(df.velocity, df.altitude)
)
df = convert_units(df_orig_units)
ax = (
    df[["altitude", "velocity", "dynamic_pressure"]]
    .plot(
        x='altitude',
        xlabel="altitude (km)",
        sharey=False,
        secondary_y=["velocity"],
        ylabel="velocity (km/s)",
    )
)
ax.set_ylabel("dynamic pressure (atm)")
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 200, 21))
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.get_legend().set_loc('upper center')
plt.show()


We can see that the maximum dynamic pressure (max q) is experienced slightly over 10 km of altitude at the speed of about 0.5 km/s, and its value is slightly over 0.25 atm. This agrees with Falcon 9 values quoted at the beginning.
Update: compressible flow at supersonic speeds
@ErinAnne pointed out that dynamic pressure is calculated differently at supersonic speeds:
$$q=p_s\left(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}M^2\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}-p_s$$
This is because incompressible fluid dynamics doesn't apply at such speeds.
I changed my code to account for this:
altitude_to_static_pressure_dict = {
    # Data from http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm
    # altitude (m): pressure (Pa)
    0:      1.01325E+5,
    1000:   8.98746E+4,
    2000:   7.94952E+4,
    3000:   7.01085E+4,
    4000:   6.16402E+4,
    5000:   5.40199E+4,
    6000:   4.71810E+4,
    7000:   4.10607E+4,
    8000:   3.55998E+4,
    9000:   3.07425E+4,
    10000:  2.64363E+4,
    12000:  1.93304E+4,
    15000:  1.20446E+4,
    20000:  5.47489E+3,
    25000:  2.51102E+3,
    30000:  1.17187E+3,
    35000:  5.58924E+2,
    40000:  2.77522E+2,
    45000:  1.43135E+2,
    50000:  7.59448E+1,
    60000:  2.03143E+1,
    70000:  4.63422,
    80000:  8.86280E-1,
}
altitude_to_static_pressure = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(altitude_to_static_pressure_dict, orient='index', columns=['pressure'])
    .rename_axis('altitude')
    .reset_index()
)
altitude_to_speed_of_sound_dict = {
    # Data from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#/media/File:Comparison_US_standard_atmosphere_1962.svg
    # altitude (m): speed (m/s)
    0: 343,
    11000: 295,
    20000: 295,
    29000: 301,
    48000: 330,
    52000: 330,
    62000: 327,
    80000: 275,
}
altitude_to_speed_of_sound = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(altitude_to_speed_of_sound_dict, orient='index', columns=['speed_of_sound'])
    .rename_axis('altitude')
    .reset_index()
)


def static_pressure(h):
    """Calculate the static pressure at altitude h (m)."""
    return np.interp([h], altitude_to_static_pressure.altitude, altitude_to_static_pressure.pressure)[0]

def speed_of_sound(h):
    """Calculate the speed of sound at altitude h (m)."""
    return np.interp([h], altitude_to_speed_of_sound.altitude, altitude_to_speed_of_sound.speed_of_sound)[0]

def dynamic_pressure(v, h):
    """Calculate dynamic pressure given velocity v (m/s) and altitude h (m)."""
    v = np.asarray(v)  # Ensure v is an array
    h = np.asarray(h)  # Ensure h is an array

    # Calculate for v < speed_of_sound
    rho = air_density(h)
    dp_subsonic = 0.5 * rho * v**2

    # Calculate for v >= speed_of_sound
    mach_number = v / speed_of_sound(h)
    gamma = 1.4  # Ratio of specific heats for air
    p = static_pressure(h)
    dp_supersonic = p * (1 + (gamma-1)/2 * mach_number**2)**(gamma-(gamma-1)) - p

    # Vectorized condition using np.where
    result = np.where(v < speed_of_sound(h), dp_subsonic, dp_supersonic)
    
    return result

Below are updated plots. They show that reasonable altitudes for achieving orbital speeds are lower than in the previous calculation, but are still measured in tens of kilometres.



Conclusion
I can only conclude that Generation 1 StarTram concept is wrong and there is simply no way to launch payload at speeds of 8-9 km/s into the air at altitudes in the range of 4-8 km. The air is still quite dense there and dynamic pressure becomes huge.
I don't know what dynamic pressure level is acceptable, but generally it seems clear that the numbers start looking reasonable at a few tens of kilometers of altitude. Therefore, we need solutions such as the Lofstrom Loop or the Tethered Ring.

Are you quite sure that the definition of dynamic pressure you used is applicable to the speeds involved?  "Incompressible fluid dynamics" doesn't apply to transonic or supersonic flow.

@ErinAnne don't know if this helps or not. I get the feeling that "dynamic pressure" is just a word that refers to the expression $$\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$$ rather than an actual pressure measured in an actual scenario. Hopefully kxmh42 will shed some light on this - I always get dizzy when people start talking streamlines, streaklines, and pathlines, inviscid, incompressible, irrotational, Reynolds, Euler,  Navier–Stokes... and Terry Tao's water problem

@uhoh it gets more complicated than that

@ErinAnne that does it - I'm officially dizzy now, going for a walk... ;-)

@ErinAnne Thanks a lot for the tips! I added a section about compressible flow at supersonic speeds and added new plots, let me know if it looks right. :)

I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion but at a glance I don't see anything else I'd correct. +1 for effort
